# Add data to mssql string to byte error c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, insert

I am trying to put some data to a MSSQL Database, which I created with Visual Basic. When I  am executing the code, I get the following errors:

```
Error   21  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'byte[]' c:\users\hussein\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\defualt.aspx.cs  32  33  WebApplication2
Error   22  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'byte[]' c:\users\hussein\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\defualt.aspx.cs  33  32  WebApplication2
Error   23  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'byte[]' c:\users\hussein\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\defualt.aspx.cs  34  34  WebApplication2
Error   24  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'byte[]' c:\users\hussein\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\defualt.aspx.cs  35  34  WebApplication2
```

Here is my code, I tried to convert the string to `byte[]`, but I have binary text in my database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class defualt : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Unnamed5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((TextBox1.Text == "" || TextBox2.Text == "" || TextBox3.Text == "" || TextBox4.Text == ""))
            {
                Label1.Text = "<h3>- Du måste fylla i alla fält, brorsan</h3>";
            }
            else
            {
                DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();
                var nyMedlem = new medlemar();
                nyMedlem.namn = TextBox1.Text;
                nyMedlem.anv = TextBox2.Text;
                nyMedlem.losen = TextBox3.Text;
                nyMedlem.epost = TextBox4.Text;
                db.medlemar.Add(nyMedlem);
                db.SaveChanges();
                Label1.Text = "<h3>- Nu är du medlem</h3>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably saving 4 text fields into a data base field which is of the format byte[], hence you are getting the conversion 4 times.

Try this : It requires a change in medlemar class.

```
string x = TextBox1.Text;
byte[] y = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x);

nyMedlem.(something of data type byte[]) = y;
```